# Parsing ics file and delete some information

Tags: python, icalendar

I want to parsing through an ics file and 'delete' some information. My script:

```
import os
from ics import Calendar
from urllib.request import urlopen

basic_path = os.getcwd()
url = "file://" + basic_path + "/original.ics"
c = Calendar(urlopen(url).read().decode())

for event in c.events:
    event.location = None
    event.description = None
    event.url = None
    event.attendees = None
    event.organizer = None

with open('new.ics', 'w') as f:
   f.writelines(c)
```

Output file is ok except for attendee(s) and organizer. Is it not working because attendees and organizer are lists?

Comment: while posting question makes sure you provide error occurring to your code.

Comment: `event.description = None` -> exclude description from each event. No rows in output file. `event.attendees = None` -> does not set attendees to none. There are still rows with ATTENDEE in my output file "new.ics".